# Link Users to external login db

Tags: login

I have to create a login form and link the login button to an external database. I already have the external database with users data. So basically, it will have to check if the user exists and redirect it to a page. Does WordPress have a plugin for this or should I hard-code?

**Note:** This login form is totally a separate form from the primary login page directing to the dashboard.

Comment: What kind of WP privileges do you want for users logging with this form to have?

Comment: A user will have to enter a username and password. Maybe I have to use an API when a user clicks on login, it can verify in the external database (which is on another domain!) if the user exists or not. Also, when the user is logged in, it has to create a session showing his username. 
Thank you for helping!